# pygame shooting multiple bullets

Tags: python, pygame

im trying to shoot multiple bullets but i can only get it to shoot 1 then i have to restart the game how do i shoot multiple bullets ive tried doing for loops but i cant get them to work

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
bg=pygame.display.set_mode((1300,640))
FPS=pygame.time.Clock()
p=x,y,width,height=(0,0,100,100)
b=b_x,b_y,b_width,b_height=(x,y,25,25)
bullets=[99]
shoot=False
def draw():
    global bullet,b_x,shoot,m
    b_x+=50
    m=b_y+50
    bullet=pygame.draw.rect(bg,(0,0,255),(b_x+100,m,b_width,b_height))
    something()

def something():
    pygame.draw.rect(bg, (0, 0, 255), (b_x + 100, m, b_width, b_height))


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                x-=50

            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x+=50

            if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
                shoot=True

bg.fill((0,0,0))
player1=pygame.draw.rect(bg,(255,0,0),(x,y,width,height))
if shoot:
    draw()

pygame.display.update()
FPS.tick(30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reload, just reset the shoot flag and bullet position.

Try this update:

```
if shoot:
    draw()
    if b_x > 1300:  # off screen
        b_x = 0
        shoot=False  # wait for space to re-shoot
```

For rapid fire, use a list to store the bullet positions. The space key adds to the bullet list. When the bullet goes off screen, remove it from the list.

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
bg=pygame.display.set_mode((1300,640))
FPS=pygame.time.Clock()
p=x,y,width,height=(0,0,100,100)
b=b_x,b_y,b_width,b_height=(x,y,25,25)
bullets=[] # all active bullets
shoot=False
def draw():
    global bullets,bullet,b_x,shoot,m
    #b_x+=50
    m=b_y+50
    for i in range(len(bullets)):
       b_x = bullets[i] # x position of bullets
       bullet=pygame.draw.rect(bg,(0,0,255),(b_x+100,m,b_width,b_height))
       bullets[i] += 50  # move each bullet
    bullets = [b for b in bullets if b < 1300] # only keep bullets on screen   

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                x-=50

            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x+=50

            if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
                bullets.append(0)  # add new bullets

    bg.fill((0,0,0))
    player1=pygame.draw.rect(bg,(255,0,0),(x,y,width,height))
    if len(bullets):  # if any active bullets
        draw()

    pygame.display.update()
    FPS.tick(30)
```

Comment: thanks for this it really helped but another question how would i do rapid fire?

Comment: Answer updated for rapid fire